# SCSS/SASS - How to Specify Two Valid Parents for Nested CSS

Tags: css, sass

**Question:** With SCSS, can we specify two different `.main` selectors? Say I want another one with `margin-top: 50px` while also inheriting all other conditions

I have inherited some SCSS from someone else. I have the following SCSS structure:

```
.main {
  margin-top: 74px;

  ul.tabs {
    position: relative;

    li.tab {
     /*The rest of nested structure*/
             }
          }
       }
```

It continues to nest (unfortunately) for many layers.

I have some other options (splitting the structure in two) which is a simple fix. Just curious if there's something better.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `@extend`

Comment: What distinguishes the second `.main` selector from the first one?

Comment: @ErinHalbmaier, the difference would be something fairly simple. In this instance, a difference in padding

Comment: Actually,  I meant : is one for a different screen size, does one have another classname with it, etc. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a mixin:

```
@mixin sharedStyles{
  //shared nested styles go here
}

.parentA{
  margin-top:74px;
  @include sharedStyles;
}

.parentB{
  margin-top: 50px;
  @include sharedStyles;
}
```

Here is a gist that illustrates the concept:

https://gist.github.com/Ryan-Haines/ba10888d0828d394851d3da6063f70bb

I recommend using sassmeister for rapid prototyping:

https://www.sassmeister.com

Answer (score 1):

If you use a placeholder, as long as one selector is not inside a media query, it should group them together in the CSS.  Ie

```
%mainStyles {
        border: 1px solid black;
}

.main1 {
    margin-top: 75px;
    @extend %mainStyles;
}

.main2 {
      margin-top: 50px;
      @extend %mainStyles;
}
```

Should generate

```
.main1, .main2 {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
.main1 {
    margin-top: 75px;
}

.main2 {
      margin-top: 50px;
}
```